# Does anything in Objective-C use associative references under the hood?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Does anything in Objective-C use associative references under the hood? For example, do property setter and getter use it behind the scene?

Comment: Nothing in the runtime uses them and the frameworks generally do not.  As you move higher up the stack, the chances of use are more likely.  On OS X, you ought -- haven't tried, but can't imagine why it wouldn't work -- to be able to write a dtrace script that dumps a backtrace whenever objc_setAssociated*() is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That would be much too slow.

Some classes in Cocoa use them, but nothing in ObjC itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would think associative references would be used explicitly by developers extending exiting classes.  When the compiler generates getters and setters it has access to the source code.

Comment: Hi I know developer can use it.  Would like to know if any construct in Objective-C uses this under the hood.

Comment: I don't think the compiler resorts to using associative references.